# Comparing dates in query activity with null values (in Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I query the _Opens data view which updates my `SubscribersMain` Data extension with the latest email open dates, I have noticed that the query blanks out the `last_open_date` when it shouldn't but cant figure out why, I suspect it happens only when the Subscriber already has a null value in the `last_opened_date` field. I can see records that absolutely do have timestamps this month, become blank.

**EDIT:**
It looks like none of the comparisons work, it always reverts to the ELSE field in the case statement.

**EDIT 2:**
Actually it looks like even when there is a value in the column, and the aggregated EventDate has a value... the query will return a blank value.

Here is my query:

```
select sub.subscriberKey,
(CASE WHEN dateadd(hour,6,MAX(o.EventDate)) > sub.last_opened_date THEN dateadd(hour,6,MAX(o.EventDate)) 
   ELSE sub.last_opened_date
END) AS last_opened_date
FROM SubscribersMain sub INNER JOIN _Open o
     ON sub.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
GROUP BY sub.SubscriberKey, Sub.last_opened_date
HAVING MAX(o.EventDate) <> ''
```

Comment: This might not be the cause of your issue but I don't see you declaring your alias for SubscribersMain.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

SFMC data extensions are based off SQL tables so the date/time field types have an auto-assigned default value. As an empty value, the system will default to this to (1/1/1900 12:00:00AM).

So try using using this data as validation to see if it delivers desired results.